# When importing two same components, does it include the css twice?

Tags: css, vue.js

I created a custom modal, it also contains some SCSS.

In some cases, I need to use the modal twice (for different use case). Does Vue import the CSS twice or does Vue know I already imported the CSS?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p-modal></p-modal>
    <p-modal></p-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: If you are using webpack to build, as I remember, when you do a production build the CSS is deduplicated.

Comment: @skribe yes I am using webpack (vue-cli)